# C sendto returns -1 if broadcasting on a vpn

Tags: c, vpn, sendto

I have built a udp server that broadcasts a message every so often. It broadcasts without a problem.  But if I turn on my vpn, then sendto will start returning -1 even though I am sending to INADDR_BROADCAST.

I am running this on a mac btw if that changes anything.  I really have no idea why this would happen, I am really wondering how could a udp broadcast fail?

Answer (score 0):

You should check errno global variable for more detailed error description. Possible values for this call described at ERRORS section of [sendto(2)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sendto.2.html) manual page.

For example:

> [EACCES]           The SO_BROADCAST option is not set on the socket and a broadcast address is given as the destination.
>
> [EHOSTUNREACH]     The destination address specifies an unreachable host.
>
> [ENETUNREACH]      No route to the network is present.

Answer (score 0):

my errno is 227 (I think) which reads

sendto: Can't assign requested address

I think it can't find a broadcasting port when my vpn gets turned on, here is an example when I turn on my vpn and turn it back off

2010-06-25 04:05:55.022 SwypeSendForMac2[63687:6203] wrote 187 bytes to socked 6
2010-06-25 04:05:56.023 SwypeSendForMac2[63687:6203] wrote 187 bytes to socked 6
2010-06-25 04:05:57.024 SwypeSendForMac2[63687:6203] wrote 187 bytes to socked 6
sendto: Can't assign requested address
sendto: Can't assign requested address
sendto: Can't assign requested address
sendto: Can't assign requested address
sendto: Can't assign requested address
sendto: Can't assign requested address
sendto: Can't assign requested address
2010-06-25 04:06:05.027 SwypeSendForMac2[63687:6203] wrote 187 bytes to socked 6
2010-06-25 04:06:06.031 SwypeSendForMac2[63687:6203] wrote 187 bytes to socked 6

the middle of course is with the vpn on

here is my roouting table **without the vpn:**

34:~ samuelw$ netstat -r
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           63        0     en1
127                localhost          UCS             0        0     lo0
localhost          localhost          UH              1   180317     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
cronos.local       link#5             UHLW            0        1     en1
192.168.1          link#5             UCS             4        0     en1
192.168.1.1        90:84:d:d3:e2:54   UHLWI          69     1260     en1   1123
192.168.1.98       0:11:24:a2:41:6d   UHLWI           0      324     en1   1112
192.168.1.152      0:21:e9:76:fe:6b   UHLWI           0        0     en1    657
192.168.1.153      localhost          UHS             0      118     lo0
192.168.1.154      0:21:5c:52:e0:11   UHLWI           1     2662     en1   1134

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags         Netif Expire
localhost          localhost          UH              lo0
fe80::%lo0         localhost          Uc              lo0
localhost          link#1             UHL             lo0
fe80::%en1         link#5             UC              en1
samuelmacbook.loca 0:1e:c2:a6:64:98   UHL             lo0
cronos.local       0:21:5c:52:e0:11   UHLW            en1
ff01::             localhost          Um              lo0
ff02::             localhost          UmC             lo0
ff02::             link#5             UmC             en1

**and with my vpn**

34:~ samuelw$ netstat -r
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            172.16.20.1        UGSc            8        0    ppp0
default            192.168.1.1        UGScI           1        0     en1
127                localhost          UCS             0        0     lo0
localhost          localhost          UH              1   180323     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
cronos.local       link#5             UHLW            0        1     en1
172.16.20.1        34.108.131.216.cli UH              9        0    ppp0
192.168.1          link#5             UCS             5        0     en1
192.168.1.1        90:84:d:d3:e2:54   UHLWI           3     1346     en1   1104
192.168.1.98       0:11:24:a2:41:6d   UHLWI           2      378     en1   1093
192.168.1.152      0:21:e9:76:fe:6b   UHLWI           0        0     en1    637
192.168.1.153      localhost          UHS             0      118     lo0
192.168.1.154      0:21:5c:52:e0:11   UHLWI           1     2665     en1   1114
192.168.1.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        2     en1
strong-sf1.reliabl 192.168.1.1        UGHS           25       25     en1
216.131.108        ppp0               USc             0        0    ppp0

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags         Netif Expire
localhost          localhost          UH              lo0
fe80::%lo0         localhost          Uc              lo0
localhost          link#1             UHL             lo0
fe80::%en1         link#5             UC              en1
samuelmacbook.loca 0:1e:c2:a6:64:98   UHL             lo0
cronos.local       0:21:5c:52:e0:11   UHLW            en1
ff01::             localhost          Um              lo0
ff02::             localhost          UmC             lo0
ff02::             link#5             UmC             en1

and here is my code split into 2 functions

- (int)startService
  {
  broadcast = 1;

  if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
      perror("socket");
      exit(1);
  }

  // this call is what allows broadcast packets to be sent:
  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast,
                 sizeof broadcast) == -1) {
      perror("setsockopt (SO_BROADCAST)");
      exit(1);
  }

  their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     // host byte order

  their_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT); // short, network byte order

  their_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);

  memset(their_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof their_addr.sin_zero);

  return 0;
  }
- (void)publishServiceLoop
  {
  NSAutoreleasePool * autoreleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSString * message;

  while (alive) {
      while ((message = [AdyNetServer encodeToXML:server]) == nil) {
          [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];
      }
      const char * msgString = [message cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      if ((numbytes=sendto(sockfd, msgString, [message length], 0,
                           (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, sizeof their_addr)) == -1) {
          perror("sendto");
          if ([[AdyErrorAlerter sharedInstance] delegate]) {
          [[[AdyErrorAlerter sharedInstance] delegate] receiveErrorMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                            @"unable to broadcast to socket %d, with message %@",sockfd,msgString]];
          }

  ```
      }
  else {
      NSLog(@"wrote %d bytes to socked %d",numbytes,sockfd);
  }

  //printf("sent %d bytes to %s\n", numbytes,
  //     inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
  [autoreleasePool release];
  autoreleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  ```

  }
  [autoreleasePool release];
  if (thread != nil) {
      thread = nil;
      [thread release];
  }
  }